# Issue for displaying tab menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I can't show the tab menu correctly and I don't find a solution.

Normally `.tab_container` should be displayed and we can switch to the second tab when we click on it.

I saw an error but I find where is the problem:

> **Uncaught "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"**

Here you can find my Codepen: https://codepen.io/tagline2020/pen/QWExZOg

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab_container:first').show();
    $('.tab_navigation li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.tab_navigation li').click(function(event){
    index = $(this).index();
    $('.tab_navigation li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.tab_container').hide();
    $('.tab_container').eq(index).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
      .container-services{
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
  }
  .tab_navigation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  
  }
  .tab_navigation li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: black;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #d4b26b;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .tab_navigation li.active{
    background: black;
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0,.71,.86,-0.21);
  }
  @keyframes shake {
    0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  }
  
  .tab_navigation li:hover{
    background: #d4b26b;
    color : black
    
  }
  .tab_container_area{
    
  }
  .tab_container{
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    padding: 10px;
    background:  white;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .tab_container p{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .skills{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px #d4b26b solid;
    color : black;
  }
  .icons_services{
    max-width: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
  }
  .service-price{
    font-weight: medium;
    color: black;
    font-size: bold;
   }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-services">
    <ul class="tab_navigation">
        <li>Femme</li>
        <li>Coloration</li>
        <li>Homme</li>
        <li>Manucure</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container_area">
        <div class="tab_container">
            <p class="skills">Brushing cheveux long<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Shampoing.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">45.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Shamp/Brushing cheveux courts<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Shampoing.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">30.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Masque nourrissant <br>Crème intensive<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Pot-creme.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">10.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Coupe Cheveux épais<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Ciseaux.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">75.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Coupe<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Ciseaux.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">66.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Coupe avant technique<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Ciseaux.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">50.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Frange<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Ciseaux.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">15.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Permanente<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Bling-Bling.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 100.- à 140.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Lissage Brésilien<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Lisseur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price"> Prix sur place</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Défrisage<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Lisseur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 135.- à 155.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Fixatif<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Bling-Bling.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 5.- à 8.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Coup de peigne<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Bling-Bling.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 25.- à 30.- CHF</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab_container">
            <p class="skills">Teinture (avec shamppoing special Majirel)<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Couleur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 100.- à 135.- CHF</span></p>
            <p class="skills">Coloration Racines/Shamp/Démélant<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Couleur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 95.- à 120.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Coloration Racines-Longueurs/Shamp/Soin<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Couleur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 95.- à 120.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Décoloration<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Couleur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 80.- à 100.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Balayage planchette<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Couleur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 90.- à 115.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Mèches au bonnet<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Couleur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 90.- à 120.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Mèches au papier<img class="icons_services" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/pages-services/Couleur.png" alt=""><span class="service-price">de 140.- à 180.- CHF</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab_container">
            <p class="skills">Coupe Homme Chx épais/Transfo<span class="service-price">55.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Coupe Homme<span class="service-price">42.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Barbe<span class="service-price">15.- CHF</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab_container">
            <p class="skills">Manucure<span class="service-price">40.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">French Manucure<span class="service-price">45.- CHF</p>
            <p class="skills">Pédicure<span class="service-price">70.- CHF</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing  jQuery CDN, include that then it will work

Comment: Thank you , is working it was that, but I don't understand something I need to have in 2 place my local jquery script in my header and my footer or it doesn't work...

Comment: Add this ``<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`` CDN just before closing of your body tab (``</body>``). You can place jQuery in the header, it is just a convention to keep jQuery(or any JS script) at the bottom so that the whole HTML document is loaded onto which the jQuery will act upon, else what will happen that jQuery will load before the HTML content, and will give an error as jQuery will not be able to find many HTML contents to work upon.

Answer (score 0):

> In my case I was putting my .js file before the jQuery script link,
> putting the .js file after jQuery script link solved my issue.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```